# Tableau: Parameter Hidden in Worksheet, Need to Show

Tags: tableau-api

Tableau newbie here so please excuse the high level question.

I have a 3 worksheets (A, B and C). All have a parameter XYZ.

1. A has a compact list that lists all the values and the data refreshes
2. B has a compact list that when the value is chosen, an action is attributed to an image which takes it to worksheet C which shows the data
3. C shows data dependent on the parameter shown/clicked in B

My question is how do I get the parameter/compact list to show in worksheet C so it refreshes the data there without the need of doing it in B?

I've tried going through the options but I feel because of my lack of experience, I am missing something obvious. I am working with Tableau 8.2

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to duplicate the parameter (right-click -> Duplicate) and use two separate but identical parameters, one on each sheet.
By design the parameters are global (i.e. control all sheets where they are used), unlike filters for which scope can be configured.